# How can I print DateTime in UTC format?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm simply trying to print a DateTime in its UTC equivalent time format. What am I doing wrong?

```
var utcEpoch = DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal); //This specifies the time I provided is in UTC
Console.WriteLine(utcEpoch.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz")); //This properly shows my UTC offset of -6, so it's not wrong
Console.WriteLine(utcEpoch.ToString("u")); //This just flat out seems wrong because it doesn't specify a timezone or offset in its output

> 1969-12-31 18:00:00 -06:00
> 1969-12-31 18:00:00Z
```

I expected to see `1970-01-01 00:00:00Z` for the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missunderstanding what the API is doing.

First thing to note is that both `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` and `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal`will still return a DateTime where Kind = Local

```
> DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).Kind
=> Local
> DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Kind
=> Local
```

So no matter what we will get a **local date**. That means that the API most likely is there to make it possible to get a local time from a UTC date. Let's try if that's correct.

I'm in Sweden so we are UTC + 1 during standard time. So if I use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` and put in todays date I should get a local date being 01:00 today.

Running this in C# Interactive:

```
> DateTime.Parse("2018-03-03", .CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, .DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
=> [2018-03-03 01:00:00]
```

Meaning C# assumed that the string I inputed was in UTC and I wanted it in local so it "fixed" it for me.

Doing the same with `AssumeLocal`.

```
DateTime.Parse("2018-03-03", .CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, .DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)
=> [2018-03-03 00:00:00]
```

As expected we now treated the input as a local string and got the same value.

**To get the date as UTC you can specify the kind**

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("2018-03-03", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("o")
=> "2018-03-03T00:00:00.0000000Z"
```

Answer (score 4):

From [The Universal Sortable (`"u"`) Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-universal-sortable-u-format-specifier) :

> Although the result string should express a time as Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC), no conversion of the original DateTime value is
>   performed during the formatting operation. **Therefore, you must convert
>   a DateTime value to UTC by calling the `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` method
>   before formatting it**. In contrast, DateTimeOffset values perform this
>   conversion automatically; there is no need to call the
>   DateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime method before the formatting operation.

Your `utcEpoch.Kind` is *not* `UTC`, it is `Local`. [DateTime's are triciker than you might think](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html). You are expecting that it will return `UTC` as `Kind` property but it is *not*. It returns `Local`.

This situation has been discussed on [Phil Haack blog post](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/01/Possible_Bug_With_DateTime.Parse.aspx/) as well and [Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) has a quite nice comment about this;

> `AssumeLocal` and `AssumeUniversal` are both related to how the input
>   string is interpreted. **By themselves, neither will change the output
>   kind.**
>
> The default output kind is `Local`. To get it to be `Utc`, you can use the
>   `AdjustToUniversal` style.
>
> The `DateTimeStyles` enum is flags-based, so you can combine these in
>   some ways that make sense. To achieve what you originally set out to
>   do (parse the input as `UTC` and output it as `UTC`), then you would use:
>
> DateTime utcDate = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2006 19:30", culture,  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
>
> As others pointed pointed out, a separate call to `ToUniversalTime()`
>   would also work, but this is technically more correct.

You can see it on [referance source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,872) as well;

```
case 'u':   // Universal time in sortable format.
if (offset != NullOffset)
{
    // Convert to UTC invariants mean this will be in range
    dateTime = dateTime - offset;
}
else if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
{
    InvalidFormatForLocal(format, dateTime);
}
```

Comment: This answer (with edits) is a perfect explanation. It makes so much more sense now :)

Comment: Actually I still have one hangup. When I output the first Console.WriteLine, it still gives me back an offset of -6 for Central Time. Why is that? This was after Assuming Universal and Adjusting To Universal flags were both set

Comment: @JoePhillips I try to give more explanation. Check it out.

Comment: @JoePhillips Setting `AssumingUniversal` and/or `AdjustingToUniversal` flags does _not_ change the result of `zzz` here. Because it reflects the current time zone offset value no matter what. That's why using `z*` kind of formats are **not** recommended with `DateTime` values. From [documentation of `zzz` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-zzz-custom-format-specifier): ++

Comment: ++ With DateTime values, the `"zzz"` custom format specifier represents the signed offset **of the local operating system's time zone** from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. It does _not_ reflect the value of an instance's `DateTime.Kind` property. For this reason, the `"zzz"` format specifier is **not** recommended for use with `DateTime` values.

Comment: The "zzz" note is key here. I was definitely overlooking that and making some bad assumptions based on it

Comment: @JoePhillips Glad to help.